# Why do we need the specific utility assumption?

Tags: microeconomics, mathematical-economics

In many microeconomic models, we read the assumption that agents have [CARA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Risk_aversion#Absolute_risk_aversion) normal utility preferences. We need the assumption of the utility to do pricing, but should someone do differently?

Namely, is there a case where we do not need utility functions to make pricing? I think this has to do with the probability measure, if it is unique or not.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One of the most important consideration for using CARA utility is tractability. CARA utility and Gaussian errors yield a certainty equivalent completely described by a simple function of the mean and variance of the Gaussian distribution..

It also turns out that maximizing expected utility in this setup is equivalent to maximizing the certainty equivalent - which is a huge advantage in settings where we want some sort of quasi linearity in wealth.